# MySQL select duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing group_id, user_id, and role_id.

Because the unique key was set wrong, there are users who are in a group twice, with different roles. Like this:

```
group_id   |   user_id   |   role_id
    1      |      1      |      1
    1      |      1      |      2 
    2      |      1      |      1
    1      |      2      |      1
    2      |      2      |      3
```

How can i find the user id's of the user where this is the case? So, in this example only user id 1?

Edit:

Because neither the answer from @Manil Liyanage nor the one from @TX Turner give me the right results, maybe i have to explain it some more;

Users can be in multiple groups, but they shouldn't be in the some group more than once. Unfortunately, because of the wrong unique key, some users now are in the same group more than once, but only with another role. How can I find the users who are in a group more than once?

Comment: If they have different roles for same group are they duplicates or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following would show you which userids are duplicated per group, and the count.

```
SELECT user_id, group_id, COUNT(group_id) cnt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id, group_id
HAVING COUNT(group_id) > 1
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't give me the right results. Please see my edit of the question.

Comment: Updated the query based on your clarification. This will show you users that are in the same group more than once, and a count of such.

Comment: The logic is correct but you don't need a subquery to aply a where clause, use HAVING instead (see my suggested edit)

Answer (score 1):

Following should work just fine for you. It shows the ida of the duplicated records

EDIT: Use the keys inside the having-count statement concatenated.

> ```
> SELECT concat(concat('Group is: ',group_id) ,
> concat(' user id : ' , user_id)) Places
> FROM table
> HAVING count(concat(group_id,concat (':',user_id))) > 1
> ```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't give me the right results. Please see my edit of the question.

Comment: @veelen change the key combibation inside the having-count statement to specify the duplicated keys. Let me know the result as i wrote it from my mobile.

Comment: This way, i get the same result as the one before; only one result with a user who isn't in a group more than once.

Comment: @veelen for the dataset you given the correct ans should be user id 1 right? There could be a problem during concatenation where key and value combination will be similar to another.  E.g. gid 12 and uid 16 could be equal to gid 1 and uid 216. Please try the edited one with a colon seperator in the middle.

Comment: The coorect ans indeed should be 1. The last query give me the same result as before: "Group is: 9 user id : 2". User with id 2 is unfortunately not in any group multiple times. The number of users in group 9 is that large, that it is hard to check visually if there are any duplicate user id's.

Comment: Veelen as per my expertise this query should be correc. Sorry as im not in a position to test this out. check for the table with a select where userid = 2 and groupid=9 to see how many records given. If you can please update the question with more test data with a result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63969/discussion-between-veelen-and-manil-liyanage).